# Google Ajax crawling is failing

Tags: ajax, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, google-search-console

I have a php ajax website that serves pages to my users like

```
  http://www.example.com/ => this has all the individual page contents like listing
  http://www.example.com/#!page1-uid => has page1 contents, uid is the unique mongoDB identifier for that page
  http://www.example.com/#!page2-uid => has page2 contents, uid is the unique mongoDB identifier for that page
```

I want google to crawl my website to index all of about 200+ pages but none of them are getting indexed

I pretty much followed and understood the google ajax crawling methods but not sure where/what i am still missing.

Here is the setup:

**.htaccess**

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (googlebot|yahoo|bingbot|baiduspider) [NC]
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_=(.*)$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ botIndex.php?QSA=%1 [QSA,L]
```

**botIndex.php**

```
$var1 = $_REQUEST['QSA'];
checks if QSA is set, if so, serves the individual page1/page2 
else gives out the default home page that has the listing of all the page links
```

When I tested using GWT ( "fetch as google" ),  here is the pattern i observe

```
  a) www.example.com/ => it gets redirected to botIndex.php and returns me all the links (default view) just as expected
  b) www.example.com/#!page1-uid => redirects to the botIndex.php and returns me all the links but ideally it should return the actual page content instead of the home page contents (not sure GWT has the ability to ask for _escaped_fragment_ to mimic googlebot)
  c) www.example.com/?_escaped_fragement_ => GWT returns "Not found" error
```

By adding few echo in the botIndex.php, What i suspect is none of the above requests shows that the "_escaped_fragment_" is caught
hence my script botIndex.php does not get the value of the QUERY_STRING (QSA) to serve the page1/page2 individual pages instead always
defaults to home page showing all the page listing.

I tested the URL's directly for botIndex.php like

```
  a) http://www.example.com/botIndex.php?_escaped_fragment_=QSA= (returns all the links )
  b) http://www.example.com/botIndex.php?_escaped_fragment_=QSA=page1-uid (returns the actual page details)
```

What am i still missing ?

I strongly believe the .htaccess has the issue which is not possibly passing the QSA to my script.

Please suggest.

UPDATE: I am still stuck. Anyone can help me with some pointers ?

Answer (score 0):

Evidently, you have problem with preserving GET parameters during rewriting. Try to debug you .htaccess directives.

Another option is to create one entry point for your php app, just like all modern frameworks do. And implement all the logic (serving html content for bots) in your php app.

Comment: Hi @alex, thanks. Any pointers on what framework to start with ? I don't use a framework generally , not that familiar.

Comment: Good point to get familiar with modern php development worklow is laravel framework: https://github.com/laravel/laravel  But all you need now is https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/.htaccess section Handle Front Controller. Using this technique you handle all http requests with your php app.